# MacBook Pro SSD filling up with empty space

Tags: icloud, catalina, ssd, storage

I've had an issue on my MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2017) running Catalina (10.15.5). For months now, I've been struggling with the issue of having my SSD filling without apparent reason, to the point where my computer become unresponsive. I then look for files to delete, which help for a bit, but the issue comes back soon after.

After running DaisyDisk, I discovered that my SSD was filled up with so called "hidden space" accounting for 338.8gb.

[image]

Daisydisk couldn't give me any other information, so I decided to look for possible large hidden files, and I found this :

[image]

at this location :
`/Users/myself/Library/Containers/com.apple.icloud.drive.fileprovider/Data/Library/Application Support/iCloudDrive/account-AD0E5A81-23C5-41AA-BC55-7671234552C/session/r/`

It looks like versioning for old files...
Is this "normal"? Can I somehow get rid of them?

Comment: That looks like the same file over and over.  Do you have Keynote open with that particular file?

Comment: No I don't. it's actually different versions of the same file

Comment: This could be an icloud issue (never seen this before).  Try contacting Apple Support - https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201232 - I'm thinking there's a bug in iCloud somewhere that's causing this file to keep "resyncing"